How to use the github API with OR queries within a repo? What is the right syntax/library?
I'm trying to use the github API to do a OR query within a repo.
Trying to do a programmatic replication of this query from the UI :
repo:open-telemetry/opentelemetry-demo AND (client OR import)
https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aopen-telemetry%2Fopentelemetry-demo+AND+%28client+OR+import%29&type=code
I do this:
import json
import requests

query = 'repo:open-telemetry/opentelemetry-demo AND (client OR import)'
params = {'q': query}

url = "https://api.github.com/search/code"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"token {<TOKEN>}",
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
}

res = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=headers)

print(res.url) # to see what URL requests sent our request to
print(json.dumps(res.json(), indent=4))

and it outputs:
https://api.github.com/search/code?q=repo%3Aopen-telemetry%2Fopentelemetry-demo+AND+%28client+OR+import%29
{
    "message": "ERROR_TYPE_QUERY_PARSING_FATAL unable to parse query!",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/search/search#search-code",
    "status": "422"
}

